# JButtons incorrect size

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton

I want to draw a 13x13 tiles board using JFrame.
Here's the code:

```
public static void drawBoard() {
    final int TILE_SIZE = 60;
    final int TILES = 13;
    JFrame jFrame = new JFrame("Board");
    jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jFrame.setSize(TILE_SIZE * TILES + 17, TILE_SIZE * TILES);
    jFrame.setResizable(false);
    JButton button = null;
    ImageIcon icon = null;
    for (int y = 0; y < TILES; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < TILES; x++) {
            button = new JButton(alphabet[x] + "" + alphabet[y]);
            button.setName(alphabet[x] + "" + alphabet[y]);
            button.setBounds(TILE_SIZE * y, TILE_SIZE * x, TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE);
            button.addActionListener(new Clicked());
            button.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            jFrame.getContentPane().add(button);
        }
    }
    jFrame.setVisible(true);
}//end drawBoard
```

Now, when I run the code, it shows me a grid of buttons, but the one at the bottom right corner is the same size of the frame.

Comment: Don't set the size of buttons directly.  Let the layout manager handle it.  As a generate rule, if you're setting dimensions UI components, your layout is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but the one at the bottom right corner is the same size of the frame.

Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. The layout manager will determine the size/location of a component based on the rules of the layout manager.

In the case of a JFrame, the default layout manager is the `BorderLayout`. When you add a component to the `BorderLayout` without using a "constraint" the component is added to the `CENTER`. However only one component can be added to the `CENTER`. So only the last component added is give a size/location by the layout manager. In this case the rule is to make the button the size of the space available in the frame.

If you want to have a grid, then you should be using a `GridLayout`. Then the layout manager will make each button the same size.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information. There are working examples for both the `BorderLayout` and the `GridLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

You should really look into a layout that handles the component size instead of setting it on the component itself (See: MIG Layout), but this should get you were you want to be.

```
public static void drawBoard(){
    final int TILE_SIZE = 60;
    final int TILES = 13;
    JFrame jFrame = new JFrame("Board");
    jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jFrame.setSize(TILE_SIZE * TILES + 17, TILE_SIZE * TILES);
    jFrame.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(TILES, TILES));
    jFrame.setResizable(false);
    JButton button = null;
    Dimension dim = new Dimension(TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE);
    for (int y = 0; y < TILES; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < TILES; x++) {
            button = new JButton(alphabet[x] + "" + alphabet[y]);
            button.setSize(dim);
            button.addActionListener(new Clicked());
            button.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            jFrame.getContentPane().add(button);
        }
    }
    jFrame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: See [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.)